# Software to list programs to start if power connected

Tags: windows-7

I've asked basically the same question [here on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/789533/make-certain-programs-run-when-connected-to-power-supply-laptop), but there's not been any responses.  I know it's not really best practice to do this, but I wonder perhaps if the question would do better on this site.

NOTE: this is for a laptop hence when I say 'connected to power' I'm talking about the computer being plugged in as opposed to running on battery power.

So what I'm looking for is a simple bit of freeware that all it does is you indicate a list of programs you want to run if the computer is plugged in.  What it does is check to see if the laptop is connected to power and if so runs the list of programs.  Otherwise it does nothing.

I think this would be a useful piece of software, simply because (as all laptop users know) there's some software that is best to run when connected to power, and sometimes only works in desktop setup (eg using KeyLemon with a webcam on an external monitor as opposed to the laptop which may not have a webcam).

Comment: I think what you are asking for should be somehow in _Task Scheduler_ if we chosen the correct **Trigger** for the task. I think it's under _Event ID_ in the _Begin the task: On an event_ option.